# `create-image` works with file-location input but fails with string-of-bytes input

Tags: images

Am wondering if anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong. Basically the commented out code fails.. thanks

```
(let* ((img-file "/tmp/x.png")
       (img-str (with-temp-buffer (insert-file-contents img-file) (buffer-string)))
       ;; (img (create-image img-str 'png))) ; inserts a small empty box
       (img (create-image img-file 'png)))   ; correctly inserts image
  (image-flush img)
  (insert-image img))
```

Answer (score 2):

`create-image` can handle both images created from a file (represented as a path string) and data (represented as a binary string). Consider that it can't tell what your intention was from a string alone and it's obvious what the issue is, you must call it in a way making clear that this is inline data we're dealing with, not a file. For this you just use the third argument with a boolean value, defaulting to `nil`.

Another issue is that Emacs assumes strings are multi-byte by default, thereby allowing for encodings such as UTF-8. This is not what you'd want for an image as it's just bytes. Also, I'd recommend to disable any unnecessary coding conversions in any case with `insert-file-contents-literally`:

```
(let* ((img-file "/tmp/x.png")
       (img-str (with-temp-buffer
                  (set-buffer-multibyte nil)
                  (insert-file-contents-literally img-file)
                  (buffer-string)))
       (img (create-image img-str 'png)))
  (image-flush img)
  (insert-image img))
```

Comment: From the docs, I see:
    `(create-image FILE-OR-DATA &optional TYPE DATA-P &rest PROPS)`
and it says:
    *Optional DATA-P non-nil means FILE-OR-DATA is a string containing image data.*
Tried adding t, but still get the same issue: `(img (create-image img-str 'png t))`

Comment: Indeed, I've tried myself now and discovered there's one more thing to do.